# Querying Mongo for a NumberLong

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongo 2.4.

I have a collection which has these two entries:

```
> db.collection.find({domain: "pow.com"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577ee9ec6f66304109769855"), "domain" : "pow.com", "mImp" : NumberLong(38), "oImp" : NumberLong(38), "vImp" : NumberLong(120), "date" : "Thu Jul 07 2016 16:46:52 GMT-0700 (PDT)", "id" : NumberLong(3847146) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577ef4c44df54be7247eb497"), "domain" : "pow.com", "mImp" : NumberLong(38), "oImp" : NumberLong(38), "vImp" : NumberLong(120), "date" : ISODate("2016-10-01T00:00:00Z"), "id" : NumberLong(3847146) }
```

I've tried to run these queries and everytime I get no data back:

```
> db.collection.find({"vImp": NumberLong(38)});
> db.collection.find({vImp: NumberLong(38)});
> db.collection.find({vImp: 38});
> db.collection.find(vImp: 38)
```

I've tried to google around, but it seems like this should be working....

Comment: i think the key is wrong , try this db.collection.find({"oImp": NumberLong(38)});

Comment: There is no record for the query you are trying, so you are not getting any data. Change the field name or the value in the find query, which will give you records.

Comment: Derp, yeah that was silly. Thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are missing the **""** around 38.

On MongoDB shell version: 3.0.14

```
db.users.find({"id":NumberLong("853969028494368768")})
```

in your case

```
db.collection.find({"vImp": NumberLong("38")})
```